# Android compose LazyVerticalGrid/Column weird behavior

Tags: android, lazycolumn

I have this weird behavior when using compose lazy column or LazyVerticalGrid

When scrolling to the top the lazy grid gets separated from the status bar

How can i prevent that ?

Giving the lazy grid a background can solve the issue but that's not what I want !

[image]

**My Code**

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(500.dp),
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(120.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {




        item(span = {
            GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
        }) {
           Header()
        }



    items(items = historyAppointments) { item ->
        AppointmentCard(item)
    }


}
```

Comment: If I were you, I would try putting it inside a scaffold.